# UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification is called any time?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I use `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`/`UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` pair to compute app running time. in callback of `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`, I record the startTime, and in callback of `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification`, I record endTime.
in most case, I find the running time is correct. but there are some special case in server's log, I find the running time is strange. like the end time is less than start time, or the end time is much more than the start time. so I suspect the `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` is not called in some times. if some one meet such kind of case, and give me some suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If you are listening for `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` in a view controller, then `viewDidLoad` is not called until after `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` is posted. So if you register for the notification in `viewDidLoad`, you'll miss the first notification, which happened before the view gets loaded. So every time your application launches, you'll miss one such notification. All subsequent notifications will be caught though, including returning from background etc.

Answer (score -1):

`UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` will be called everytime your application is coming from background to forgnound.means everytime your application is becoming active from a nonactive state.I think that is the reason for the changing time.

Comment: thanks for your answer first. but in my experiment, UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification will also be called every time when the application is becoming nonactive from active state. so the end time will always bigger than the start time. but I found some logs on the server that show the end time is less than the start time. how do you explain this?

Comment: do u know what is the differernce between viewdidload and viewwillappear